# Android JobScheduler multiple threads

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I'm using JobScheduler to send an email every 15 minutes. The JobScheduler is scheduled in MainActivity onCreate and therefore every time main activity is opened, the email gets sent. but after 15 minutes only one email is sent at a time. I want the action to happen only once every 15 minutes not everytime the onCreate of MainActivity is called.

```
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), JobSchedulerService.class);
    JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(1, componentName).setPeriodic(900000).setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY).build();

    JobScheduler jobScheduler =
            (JobScheduler) getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
```

This is my onStart in jobService class

```
   public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
    this.params = params;
    String filename = "TodaysRecords.csv";
    this.dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
    File recordsFile = dbHandler.exportDB(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), filename);

    String receiverEmail = dbHandler.returnEmail();

    String[] recipients = { receiverEmail };
    SendEmailAsyncTask email = new SendEmailAsyncTask();
    //email.activity = this;
    email.m = new Mail("someemail", "password");
    email.m.set_from("someemail");
    email.m.setBody("Attached is today's records from in&out android application");
    email.m.set_to(recipients);
    email.m.set_subject("In&Out Records");
    try {
        email.m.addAttachment(recordsFile.getAbsolutePath().toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    email.execute();

    return false;
}
```

Comment: are you calling `jobFinished` in on your `postExecute` ?
Also, you can move scheduling from mainactivity to application class to avoid launching it every time app is opened.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule your job in a broadcast receiver listening for the boot completed intent. After installing your app, a user must open it once before the boot completed broadcast begins being sent. The job will then be scheduled on every boot. Please comment if the scheduling must be done in your MainActivity onCreate().

```
public class BootCompletedRcvr extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // check for boot complete intent
    if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Context mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(
            mContext, JobSchedulerService.class);
        JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(1, componentName)
            .setPeriodic(900000)
            .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
            .build();

        JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)
                 mContext.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
    }
}
}
```

Be sure to declare this in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

And this:

```
<receiver android:name=".BootCompletedRcvr">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

First:
you should add JobInfo to JobScheduler in ApplicationClass 
Second:
inside of

```
onPostExecute
```

method call JobFinish with false like below

```
jobFinished(params,false)
```

and it should be work :)